# Aspose.words. Range.replace() ignores timeSpan

Tags: timespan, regexp-replace, aspose, aspose.words

I have such problem:
A use aspose.words.range.replace with regex with timespan.FromSeconds(7).
So I expect that replace method throws exption when it can not find match in 7 sec.
But in that case program freezes.

So, maybe there are any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: The issue has been reported in Aspose.Words forum https://forum.aspose.com/t/range-replace-does-not-throwing-regexmatchtimeoutexception-in-net/241354/2

Answer (score 0):

The requested feature is supported starting from [22.3 version of Aspose.Words](https://downloads.aspose.com/words/net/new-releases/aspose.words-for-.net-22.3/).